# Trying to read XML from Oracle database to create MD5 hash

Tags: java, xml, oracle, jdbc

I have a program where I am trying to retrieve different datatypes from oracle table and convert the row into MD5 hash.

ByteArrayOutputStream sqlResultSetRow = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

```
ByteArrayOutputStream sqlResultSetOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();              switch (columnType) {
            case Types.NUMERIC:
              String integerValue = Integer.toString(rs.getInt(col));
              if(!rs.wasNull()){
                sqlResultSetRow.write(integerValue.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, integerValue.length());
              }
              break;
            case Types.FLOAT:
              String floatValue = Float.toString(rs.getFloat(col));
              if(!rs.wasNull()){
                sqlResultSetRow.write(floatValue.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, floatValue.length());
              }
              break;
case Types.CLOB:
              InputStream ins = rs.getBinaryStream(col);
              if(!rs.wasNull()){
                sqlResultSetRow.write(getCLOBValue(ins));
              }
              break;
sqlResultSetRow.writeTo(sqlResultSetOut);    ComputeLNMD5Hash(new ByteArrayInputStream(sqlResultSetOut.toByteArray()))
```

WHen I retrieve XML type from table I get a SYS.xmltype and not Types.SQLXML. What is the difference between them and How can I convert SYS.xmltype to Byte[] so I can write it to the bytearrayoutputstream to calculate the hash of the overall row.

Comment: it's not the answer on question but you can use `dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.MD5` to generate haskey

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Hi user, Do you have problems with your database code, or with MD5 code?

Comment: I think its the database code he has problems with as to how to get XML as bytes to compute the MD5.  Maybe like this https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10790/xdb11jav.htm

Comment: if you can handle CLOB values, why not select the XMLtype as a clob? (try getCLOBVal() )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this :-

```
 if(rsmd.getColumnTypeName(col).equals("SYS.XMLTYPE")){
            OracleResultSet orset = (OracleResultSet) rs;
            if(orset.getOPAQUE(col) != null) {
            XMLType poxml = XMLType.createXML(orset.getOPAQUE(col));
            sqlResultSetRow.write(poxml.getStringVal().getBytes("UTF-8"));
            }
          }
```